# How to avoid stopping JS execution after receiving HTTP 403 from REST API

Tags: javascript, rest, frontend, web-frontend

I'm building a frontend for a REST API. Sometimes you get a HTTP 403 (Forbidden) when accessing some resources, which is perfectly fine and expected. However, once this response is received, all the frontend JS code stops executing and page won't work until you refresh the page. Obviously this isn't acceptable. How should I handle this?

For example, let's take a typical GET request with jQuery:

```
$.get("http://example.com/user/3/", function() {
  console.log('ok');
  }).fail(function() {
    console.log('oh no!');
  })
});
```

If the GET request receives a 403, then the rest of the JS code stops working.

Comment: JS scripts stops execution only when an unhandled exception it thrown. Are there any errors in a console?

Comment: Have you added a check to only proceed when status is 200?

Comment: I've added an example of how the requests are written in my code.